# Haskell - Read a file containing numbers into a list

Tags: file, haskell, io

So I have a text file in this format:

`1 3 4 5 1 3 9 12 5`

Say this file is called `numbers.txt`.

I want to tell Haskell to read from the file, and put those numbers in a list. So I would end up with:

`[1,3,4,5,1,3,9,12,5]`

I really don't understand how to do this, and I've been searching a lot. I know I'll need to use getLine, but then what? Would I use a function to map that string to a list? I'm really not sure how I would write this, and I know it's probably a really stupid question, but I just started learning Haskell and I want to go forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In so many lines...

```
getNumbers :: String -> [Int]
getNumbers str = -- left as exercise
                 -- helpful functions: `read`, `words`

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "numbers.txt"
    let numbers = getNumbers contents
    print numbers
```

Comment: I got the getNumbers function on my own! Thank you so much! I knew I had to do something like that, I just wasn't sure of myself.

Comment: @Tetramputechture You could edit your function into the answer.