# Haskell: read a text file of doubles and assign a list containing them to a list variable

Tags: haskell, io, monads

Okay, I'm new to the Haskell community having come from Python and this is driving me crazy.

I have a text file looking something like:
"1.2
1.423
2.43".

I want to read this text file and store it as a list of doubles in list_var. So list_var = [1.2,1.423,2.43]. This list_var will be used further in the program.

I just don't seem to find an answer on how to do this, most answers can print out list_var, e.g. [Haskell - Read a file containing numbers into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236072/haskell-read-a-file-containing-numbers-into-a-list) but I need list_var further down the line!

I have tried:

```
get_coefficients :: String -> [Double]
get_coefficients file_1 = do
 coefficients_fromfile <- readLines "test2.txt"
 let coefficients = map readDouble coefficients_fromfile
 return coefficients
```

which doesn't work, readLines is

```
readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines = fmap lines . readFile
```

and readDouble is

```
readDouble :: String -> Double
readDouble = read
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have an IO action in a non-IO function. You should do `readLines` in your `main` function, and pass the result to `get_coefficients`, which is how that answer you linked does it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `return`, your output is in a monad, in this case the `IO` monad. As the error message tells you, you should change this line:

```
get_coefficients :: String -> [Double]
```

To this:

```
get_coefficients :: String -> IO [Double]
```

This is because of a core principle of Haskell: referential transparency.

If you want to use the `[Double]` produced, you still have to keep it in an `IO` monad, like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- This can be thought of as taking out values from the monad,
    -- but requires the promise that it'll be put back into a monad later.
    doubles <- get_coefficients "This argument does nothing, why?"
    -- This prints the list of doubles. Note: it returns an IO (),
    -- thus fufills the promise!
    -- print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
    print doubles
```